# Generating a raw bit stream as an output to pipe in another software

Tags: c, unix, random, pipe, bin

So, I have been struggling with the following problem:
I have a text file with millions of random numbers. They are pure text. I want to pipe it out to the input of another software that was supposed to get a bit stream (Dieharder is the software).
It works with the /dev/urandom, like:

```
cat /dev/urandom | ./dieharder <options>
```

I've created a C routine like that to generate the binary raw output stream. It Converts the the ASCII code to decimal (like 0x0F = 15), and stream it out to stdout:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int ASCIItoDec(char c);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fpr;
    FILE *fpw;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    size_t size=0;
    char c;       
    unsigned int *buffer; 
    char *filename;
    buffer = (unsigned int *) malloc(100);
    filename = (char *) malloc(128);

    if (argc != 2) 
    {
        scanf("%s", filename);
        fpr = fopen(filename, "rb");
    }
    else 
    {
        filename = (char *) realloc(filename, strlen(argv[1] + 1));
        strcpy(filename, argv[1]);
        fpr = fopen(filename, "rb");
    }
    if (fpr == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    while (c = fgetc(fpr) != EOF)
    {
        size++;
    }
    rewind(fpr);
    buffer = (int *) realloc(buffer, (size)*sizeof(int));
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    i=0;
    c = fgetc(fpr);
    while (c != EOF)
    {
       if ((c != ' ') && (c != '\r') && (c != '\n') && (c != '\t'))
       {
            buffer[i] = (unsigned int) ASCIItoDec(c);
       }
       else if (c == ' ')   
       { 
            buffer[i] = ' ';
       }
       c = fgetc(fpr);
       i++;
    }   
    fclose(fpr);
    i=0;
    //streaming output
    fwrite(buffer, size*sizeof(buffer), 1, stdout);
    return 0;   
}
```

The Dieharder software exits informing EOF was reached with out performing any analysis.
What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: `while (c = fgetc(fpr) != EOF)` is wrong. Should be `while ((c = fgetc(fpr)) != EOF)`, but you also need to declare `c` as an `int`, not a `char`.

Comment: im sorry about that. ASCIItoDEC is just a function that converts ASCII to hex. I will edit and add the headers.

Comment: `memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));` makes no sense. `sizeof buffer` gives you the size of a pointer (i.e. `sizeof (unsigned int *)`).

Comment: thanks it should be size*sizeof(buffer)

Comment: You're using `buffer` with different "units": The initial allocation is `malloc(100)` (i.e. 100 bytes). Then it gets resized to `(size)*sizeof(int)` (i.e. `size` ints). The `memset` treats it as a single pointer. Finally the `fwrite` treats it as `size*sizeof(buffer)` (i.e. `size` pointers). None of this fits together.

Comment: @cleveraintwise If anything, it should be `size * sizeof *buffer` or `size * sizeof (unsigned int)`.

Comment: `strlen(argv[1] + 1)` is an off-by-two error. The following `strcpy(filename, argv[1]);` call writes two bytes past the end of the allocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with the software input file rules.
Binary file has been generated correctly.
Thanks.